# Does merge direction matter in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge, dvcs

Take a simple example: I'm working on the default branch, have some changesets committed locally, and I pulled a few more from the master repository. I've been working for a few days in my isolated local repository, so there's quite a few changes to merge before I can push my results back into master.

```
default ---o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o  (pulled stuff)
            \
             o----o------------o  (my stuff)
```

I can do two things now.

Option #1:

```
hg pull
hg merge
```

Result #1:

```
default ---o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
            \                   \
             o----o------------o-O
```

Option #2:

```
hg pull
hg update
hg merge
```

Result #2:

```
default ---o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-O
            \                   /
             o----o------------o
```

These two results look isomorphic to me, but in practice it seems that option #2 results in way smaller changesets (because it only applies my few changes to the mainline instead of applying all the mainline changes to my few).

My question is: does this matter? Should I care about the direction of my merges? Am I saving space if I do this? (Doing `hg log --patch --rev tip` after the merge suggests so.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're (effectively) identical.  You see a difference in the `hg log --patch --rev X` output size because log shows the diff of the result and (arbitrarily) its 'left' parent (officially p1), but that's not how it's stored (Mercurial has a binary diff storage format that isn't patch/diff based) and it's now how it's computed (p1, p2, and most-recent-common-ancestor are all used).

The only real difference is, if you're using named branches, the branch name will be that of the left parent.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a difference if you are using Bookmarks. When doing a merge, the branch that you are is the branch that is receiving the changes, so the new changeset will be part of that branch. Supose you have this situation:

```
default ---o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o   -- Head: Rev 200
            \
             o----o------------o   -- Head: Rev 195, Bookmark: my-stuff
```

If you merge Rev 200 into Rev 195, the bookmark `my-stuff` will move on to Rev 201, as you are generating a new changeset in the same branch that has the bookmark.

On the other hand, if you merge 195 into 200, you are generating a changeset in the branch that don't have the bookmark. The `my-stuff` bookmark will remain in Rev 195.

Comment: This is particularly important if you are using [Hg-Git](http://hg-git.github.com/), because that tracks the position of the virtual Git branches using bookmarks. If you merge the wrong way, the Git branch bookmark won't move, and you'll have nothing to push.

Comment: Merging 200 into 195 isn't guaranteed to move the bookmark forward to 201.  If you do `hg update my-stuff ; hg merge 200` it will, but if you do `hg update 195 ; hg merge 200` it won't. The update by bookmark name makes it *active*.