# Clean revision history in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm new with Mercurial and I'm still trying to establish a workflow.

I clone a remote repository.  I then make changes and commits to my local repository.  I would like to push a clean revision history.  I don't want to push some revisions that may only muddy the remote repository (e.g. typo rename of methods, adding of javadoc, removing whitespaces, etc).  Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you wish to completely avoid pushing some changes or having a 'clean' history while keeping all your changes?

Comment: I want to avoid pushing some changes. I want to push only the relevant ones

Comment: Might be possible, but as each commit only contains 'diffs', you may loose things. I'm worried when you talk about renames of methods

Comment: I'm talking simply about minor typo renames like from "execte" to "execute" for example. No changes on its intent.

Comment: Another example: I create a new method called "execute". Commit #1. Made some changes. Commit #2. I then renamed the method to "run". Commit #3. I changed my mind, renamed it back to "execute". Commit #4. I don't want to push commit #3 because it does not make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed there are cases when it makes sense to prune/strip/polish changesets or to separate private/in-progress and public/ready changes. Here are some suggestion how to handle this with Mercurial:

1. If you made a series of small commits (which is a good thing), but you prefer to publish them as one changeset (which makes sense if you committed - possibly contradicting - snapshot changesets), use the **[collapse](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension)** extension:

   ```
   $ hg collapse -r <first-ref>:<last-ref> # both revs including
   ```
2. If you just have changes you want to keep private while others you want to publish, either (a) use **mercurial queues** for you private changes or (b) commit you private-only changes in an own **branch** ([named, bookmarked, or cloned](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/)) and regularly merge it with the public branch. The latter requires you to switch between branches quite often if you commit private and public changes alternating.

---

**UPDATE**

To illustrate option 2.b, consider this graph of changesets:

```
0--1--4--5---8--9   <= public/stable branch
    \     \
     2--3--6--7     <= private/dev branch
```

This means you've made changes `2` and `3` on the *dev* branch. Then you did some work on the *stable* branch (revisions `4` and `5`). These changes also make sense in *dev*, so you merge them into *dev* (revision `6`). Finally you make another experimental change in *dev* (revision `7`) and some ready-to-publish improvements in *stable* (revisions `8` and `9`). You can now publish (i.e. push to the remote repository) the changes made in *stable*, by running

```
$ hg push -r 9     # or `-r stable` if the branch is named or bookmarked as such
```

All private changes will stay local!

Note that if you plan to polish your private commits later (e.g. collapse them to one changeset), you must not merge in the stable branch (collapse cannot work across merges). Instead, [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) you private changes whenever you want them to be in sync with the latest changes in *stable*.

Comment: In option 2b, after I merge from my own private branch into a new "stable" branch, will the revision history from my private branch be pushed to the remote repository too?

Comment: You should merge the stable branch into the private one (not vice versa), i.e. update to your private branch, run `hg merge stable` and commit the merge. Now the merge is part of the private branch and won't be published when pushing the stable branch (e.g. `hg push -r stable` or `hg push -r <latest-rev-in-stable>`).

Comment: Concerning merge directions, see also: [Differences merging repository A->B vs B->A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5594731/151299).

Comment: Oben, I get your point, but I also need to push changes to the remote repository. My issue here is to be able to push some changes, but not some revisions that I've done on my private branch.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question about revision control systems in general than about mercurial. Personally I would push everything, what you're suggesting kinda goes against versioning systems purposes.

However if you want to read more about hg workflows, try having a look at this [guide](http://mercurial.selenic.com/guide/) or this [wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Workflows).

You could also be interested in the [rollback](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#rollback) command, that enables you to fix the latest commit.

**edit**: the option I would go for is to keep two branches: one identical to the remote repository where you commit only "official" changes, and one where you merge new official commits and make additional private commits.

Comment: "what you're suggesting kinda goes against versioning systems purposes": OTOH, git has a lot of tools for "rewriting history" and cherry-picking and cleaning up private commits into publishable versions.

Comment: It's absolutely true, that's why I wrote "personally" :) Git tools for rebasing, cherry-picking and so on doesn't really destroy or change anything, the old commits are still recoverable for a quite long time. However he's not talking about little changes for publishable version, he spoke of avoiding to push method renamings, javadoc... theyre quite important changes.

Comment: You can have a look at this [guide on branches](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/) in order to choose.

Answer (score 1):

If all the parasitic changes have been made at last, you can simply strip them.

If not, you can try to use the Patch Queue to remove the unnecessary commits:

- Import your changes one by one to MQ and unapply the patches
- Delete the patches that match the changes you don't want
- reapply the remaining patches

This will work for small commits. Please if you try this, do it on a clone of your local repo to avoid loss.

Also, take care not to alter an already 'shared' (pushed) history.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I'll try to explore Patch Queue.

Answer (score 0):

[Histedit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension) also can be usable and more easy (than MQ) solution for editing history